# Javascript: How to create ES5 lib with ES6

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm working with GoogleAppsScript.
I'm trying to have my code locally in order to:
- use github
- write ES6

I'm using webpack, and generating a bundle that will run in a html page is not a problem. `But I don't know for now how to generate a bundle that I will be able to copy/paste to GoogleAppsScript.`

The **main.js** file that I create is something like that :

```
import Point from './Point.js'
import Test from './test.js'
import SpreadSheetLogger from './SpreadSheetLogger.js'
```

And when I look to the **bundle** I have something like that:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    'use strict';

    function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { 'default': obj }; }

    var _PointJs = __webpack_require__(1);

    var _PointJs2 = _interopRequireDefault(_PointJs);

    var _testJs = __webpack_require__(2);

    var _testJs2 = _interopRequireDefault(_testJs);

    var _SpreadSheetLoggerJs = __webpack_require__(4);

    var _SpreadSheetLoggerJs2 = _interopRequireDefault(_SpreadSheetLoggerJs);

    var a = new _PointJs2['default'](1, 2);

/***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    "use strict";

    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
        value: true
    });

    var _createClass = (function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; })();

    function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

    var Point = (function () {
        function Point(x, y) {
            _classCallCheck(this, Point);

            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        _createClass(Point, [{
            key: "toString",
            value: function toString() {
                return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
            }
        }]);

        return Point;
    })();

    exports["default"] = Point;
    module.exports = exports["default"];

/***/ },
/* 2 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    "use strict";

    [....]

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

So if I look summarize, it's something like that:

```
(function(modules) {
   WebPack code
}([
   module1,
   module2,
   ...
])
```

But if I copy/paste that code to the javascript of a browser, I'm unable to use the different modules.

If I extract the `modules` from the bundle and `copy/paste` to the js console in a browser, this time it works.

---

I'm sure that webpack/babel can generate the code I need, but I can't find how.

Comment: Nothing about modules is global. I'm not familar with google apps script, do you just need to expose some functions on the `window`?

Comment: Yes, I need to expose some class. My problem comes from that my bundle doesn't expose them for now.

Comment: Can you do that yourself in your `main` like `window.Point = Point`?

Comment: `window` does not exist.
I've just gone in that solution for browser : `(function(root) { class MyClass { ... }; root.MyClass = MyClass; })(window)` but I can't find the object corresponding to `window` in Google App Script.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `webpack expose-loader` and to move the import/require of the different files to the main.

---

Here is an example of setup:

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "appName",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Code for a google sheet project",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "npm install && webpack --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "*",
    "babel-loader": "*",
    "node-libs-browser": "*",
    "webpack": "*",
    "expose-loader": "*"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/out',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loader: 'babel-loader'}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    stats: {
        colors: true
    }
};
```

**main.js**:

```
require("expose?Test!./Test.js");

// note here that this line replace
//    `import {SpreadSheetLogger} from 'SpreadSheetLogger.js'`
//    in test.js
require("expose?SpreadSheetLogger!./SpreadSheetLogger.js");
```

**test.js**:

```
// import {SpreadSheetLogger} from 'SpreadSheetLogger.js' is not needed
//   as the import is done in the main.js
export default class Test {
    runAllTests() {
        this.test_logger()
    }

    test_logger() {
        var log = new SpreadSheetLogger()
        log.info("This is an info")
    }
}
```

**SpreadSheetLogger.js**:

```
export default class SpreadSheetLogger {
    constructor() {
        this.loggerSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ImportLog");
    }

    info(data) {
     Logger.log(data);
     this.loggerSheet.appendRow([new Date(), "INFO", data]);
    }
}
```