# Any official way to block the client function till the google.script.run return

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Could someone please help in controlling the flow of the google script code. Simply, I need to

1. extract data from google sheet.
2. **then** & only **then** represent it in the UI.

The [google.script document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) says that:

> google.script.run is an **asynchronous** client-side JavaScript API available in HTML-service pages that can call server-side Apps Script functions.

However, In my case I need to wait until server function return its value.

**Note** [No Promise()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561735/are-there-promises-on-google-apps-script) in google script .

**Note** I have tried many mixtures of callback but without luck.

The following code is simulated from my native script & produce the same error.
I expect to have the following log :

> line NUM:1 start
>
> line NUM:2 , registerdProducts length =  1004
>
> lineNUM: 3 Data has been retrieved
>
> line NUM:4 Build UI

But I have undesirable flow of the code, with unexpected log

> line NUM:1 start
>
> lineNUM: 3 Data has been retrieved
>
> line NUM:4 Build UI
>
> line NUM:2, registerdProducts length =  1004

the most important impact that: the `createRows` is called before preperation of its data  & the UI will show nothing.

This is the `Javascript.html` code:

```
<script>
var sheetId            = "MyID";
var productsRange      = "Variables!I2:I"
var registeredProducts =[];

function onSuccessDo(products){
 /// assign the product list to the registeredProduct (global variable) .
 registeredProducts=products;
 console.log("line NUM:2, registerdProducts length = " , registeredProducts.length )
 };


function createRows(){
/// This function will add the prodducts to the UI
console.log("line NUM:4, Build UI" )
for (var x in registeredProducts , x < registeredProducts.length , x++){
    ///Adding the product in rows. 
    }
 }

function getProducts(){
/// This function will retrive the products from ths sheet & assign them to the global variable registeredProducts
console.log("line NUM:1, start")
var products = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessDo)
                                  .getDataFromSheet( sheetId, productsRange);
console.log("line NUM: 3, Data has been retrieved")
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
getProducts();
createRows();
/// use registeredProducts in other functions
/// here
       });
```

& This the `getDataFromSheet` function in `Code.js`:

```
function getDataFromSheet(ID , range){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID)  
  data = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();
  for (x in data ){
      if (data[x] == "" ){
          delete data[x]
          }}

 return   data;    
 }
```

Comment: Why downvoting? How can I improve the question if there is no comments.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways:

1. You can load data on the server-side and push it to the client-side as a variable.
2. Your case (loading from client)

1) `Server.gs`:

```
template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('client.html');
template[some key] = 'some val';
```

2)

`Javascript.html`

```
<script>
var sheetId            = "MyID",
    productsRange      = "Variables!I2:I",
    registeredProducts = [];

function onSuccessDo(products)
{
    registeredProducts = products;
    console.log("line NUM:2, registerdProducts length = ", registeredProducts.length );
    console.log("line NUM:3, Data has been retrieved");
    createRows();
};


function createRows()
{
    console.log("line NUM:4, Build UI");
    for(var x in registeredProducts , x < registeredProducts.length , x++)
    {
        // code...
    }
}

function getProducts()
{
    console.log("line NUM:1, start")
    google.script.run
                    .withSuccessHandler(onSuccessDo)
                    .getDataFromSheet(sheetId, productsRange);
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    getProducts();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, The first choice is static way to load data only one time at the start of the execution.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need to call the "createRows" funcion after the "DOMConentLoaded", not after getting data from the server side. because First: before that event we got error from createRows (undefined objects) &second we call 'getProducts' then 'getPrices' etc & finally 'createRows'

Comment: @tabebqena, in this case, you will have to make a chain of calls and in each onSuccess function add the next function call.

Comment: Is there is a better way

Comment: @tabebqena, unfortunately, I didn't find