# How to run a function after a GAS function has really ended?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, promise, async-await

How to make this otherFunc() run after myFunc has really ended?

```
async function func() {
  const res = await (() => new Promise(r => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((e) => r(myFunc(e))).serverFunc()))();
  console.log(res);
  otherFunc();          //this function still executed before myFunc end, except i use setTimeOut
  console.log("done");
}
```

This is what is inside of myFunc()

```
function myFunc(){
  var tbody = document.getElementById("table-permintaan");
  var thead = tbody.firstElementChild;
  while (tbody.hasChildNodes())  
    tbody.removeChild(tbody.firstChild);
  tbody.appendChild(thead);
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(nama){
   dataArray.forEach(function(r){
     justCreatingTableRows();
  }).listNamaBarang();
}
}
```

This is what is inside of otherFunc()

```
function otherFunc(){
   var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  var mdls = document.getElementsByClassName("modal_detail");
  var cds = document.getElementsByClassName("close_detail");
  for(var i = 0;i<btns.length-1;i++){
     btns[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
         document.getElementById("mdl"+this.id.slice(3)).style.display = "block";
     });
     mdls[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for(var i=0;i<cds.length;i++){
     cds[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
        for(var j = 0;j<mdls.length;j++){
        console.log(this.id.slice(3) , mdls[j].id);
        if (this.id.slice(3) == mdls[j].id.slice(3)) {
           mdls[j].style.display = "none";
           return;
        }   
     }
     });
  }
}
```

Using promise didn't make the otherFunc() run after myFunc(), I still need to use setTimeOut which is not good for this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there promises on Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561735/are-there-promises-on-google-apps-script)

Comment: I think that in your script, when `func()` is run, `serverFunc()`, `myFunc(e)` and `otherFunc()` are run in order. For example, can you add the script of `myFunc()` to your question? I would like to confirm your situation.

Comment: i made some edits

Comment: You need to use `async-await` on all `google.script.run` calls. Order of execution: `serverFunc()` >``myFunc()``>`otherFunc()`. However, `myFunc()` execution finishes before `function(nama)` is executed.

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. About `myFunc()`, please modify it like `func()` as @TheMaster 's comment. As other points, I think that `myFunc()` is incomplete. Because I think that an error occurs at `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(nama){dataArray.forEach(function(r){justCreatingTableRows();}).listNamaBarang();`, because of the syntax error. And is `dataArray` declared at elsewhere? Please confirm it again.

Comment: but it all works well if i write like this:

    `async function func() {
         const res = await (() => new Promise(r => 
         google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((e) => r(myFunc(e))).serverFunc()))();
         console.log(res);
         setTimeout(otherFunc,5000);   
         console.log("done");
     }`

Comment: I think that your replying is one of several answers. As other answer, I posted about above comment as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your script is modified, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `google.script.run` is also used in the function of `myFunc()`. google.script.run is run with the asynchronous process. By this, when `func()` is run, `serverFunc()`, `myFunc(e)` and `otherFunc()` in order, while `function(nama)` of `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(nama){  })).listNamaBarang()` is run out of this order. By this, the issue in your question occurs. This has already been mentioned by [TheMaster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423846/how-to-run-a-function-after-a-gas-function-has-really-ended#comment103190512_58423846).

  - In order to avoid this, please modify `myFunc()` like `func()`.

#### Modified script:

```
async function myFunc() {
  var tbody = document.getElementById("table-permintaan");
  var thead = tbody.firstElementChild;
  while (tbody.hasChildNodes())  
    tbody.removeChild(tbody.firstChild);
  tbody.appendChild(thead);

  // Below script was modified.
  const res = await (() => new Promise(r => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(nama) {
    dataArray.forEach(function(r){justCreatingTableRows(r)});
    return r("done at myFunc()");
  }).listNamaBarang()))();
  console.log(res) // done at myFunc()
}
```

- In this case, I think that other functions are not required to be modified.
- This modification supposes that `dataArray` is declared.

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

  - > `google.script.run` is an asynchronous client-side JavaScript API available in HTML-service pages that can call server-side Apps Script functions.

Comment: this modification is perfect. arigato gozaimasu ^_^

Comment: @Makoto Daiwa Ambara Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.