# Google Apps Script Javascript Standard Support

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Simple question: Can anyone point to a resource or knows anything about which standard of Javascript is supported in Google Apps Script?

I assume naturally that ES5 is fully supported, but what about ES6 (and even 7)?

Note: I mean the built-in code editor, which will appear if you open a Spreadsheet (for example), and click `Tools > Script editor...`

Comment: Anyone who would know the answer is more likely to see your question and answer it at the [Apps Script Group - LINK](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102471985047225101769)  I don't know of any official documentation for this.  Issues related to this have been discussed in the Apps Script group, for example:  let and const are part of es6 specification, and have not been implemented in the Apps Script js engine.  (As far as I know, at this moment in time)  Whether Apps Script server side code supports something is probably just trial and error.

Comment: Thanks @SandyGood - I'll transfer the question.

Comment: `const` is valid in Apps Script btw, but `let` is (currently) not

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features) Apps Script is based on [JavaScript 1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6).

[This table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Version_correspondence) explains the correlation to the ES standards.

Comment: Thanks! Oddly searches didn't lead to this page. Just what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Playing with Google Sheets custom functions right now  It doesn't like `let` but it does like `var`.  Apparently `const` is ok.  But 1.6 has let, const, etc.  Oh,well.

Comment: @Paul thanks for the update. A lot has changed since summer '16. :)

Comment: The Mozilla page says 1.6 corresponds to "ECMA-262 Edition 3". So that is earlier than ES5?

Comment: There isn't a "Version_correspondence" table anymore.

Answer (score 3):

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features (January 27, 2019)

> **Basic JavaScript features**
>
> Apps Script is based on
>   [JavaScript 1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6),
>   plus a few features from
>   [1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7) and
>   [1.8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8).
>   Many basic JavaScript features are thus available in addition to the built-in
>   and [advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced): you can
>   use common objects like
>   [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array),
>   [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date),
>   [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp),
>   [and so forth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference),
>   as well as the
>   [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) and
>   [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
>   global objects. However, because Apps Script code runs on Google's servers (not
>   client-side, except for [HTML-service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) pages),
>   browser-based features like DOM manipulation or the
>   [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) API are not
>   available.

Comment: Do you know whether there is any other more exact specification especially which `1.7` and `1.8` features are available as an alternative to just trying something out and finding it doesn't work (like arrow functions)?

Answer (score 2):

In the native editor it appears you are limited to an earlier version of JS (~ES5).

[There is an official tool called "Clasp" though](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/typescript), which lets you write typescript (`.ts`) files with ES6+ syntax and then compile & upload your files to Drive with `clasp push --watch`.

Alternatively, you can use Webpack in your local setup as [detailed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820120/using-transpiled-es6-in-google-apps-script-referenceerror-someclass-is-not/36974185#36974185).

Answer (score -11):

My guess is AngluarJS is since it was made by a google developer.

Comment: I didn't quite get that. AngularJS is not a standard of JS, and isn't used in Apps Script. I wasn't asking which framework was Google Drive implemented in, if this is what you intended.