# Is there a Google app scripts function reference?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was trying to create a function that takes a number of minutes and outputs it in a nice readable format.  For instance, `FORMATMINUTES(1570)` would output `1d2h10m`, but I got hung up trying to find a truncate function.  I also had to change my `let`s to `var`s.  Is there a reference that tells you what javascript features are available when writing custom functions?

To simplify I created two functions.  First, the `Math.trunc()` function doesn't seem to exist as it doesn't show up as a suggestion and throws an error when used:

```
function MYTRUNC(input) {
  return Math.trunc(input);
}
```

[image]

Second I thought that maybe I could use sheets's built-in `TRUNC` function, but that isn't defined either:

```
function MYTRUNC2(input) {
  return TRUNC(input)
}
```

[image]

I read [google's guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) but it says "Custom functions are created using standard JavaScript" but not what version of javascript.  Apparently it doesn't support `let`.

Their [app scripts reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) has a lot of information on interacting with sheets, but not a basic or complete reference.  I realize that in this situation I can use `Math.floor` which is available or subtract `input % 1`, but I'd like to know what other idiosyncrasies there might be, and if I can use newer javascript features.  Template literals give an error as well, so maybe it's based on an earlier javascript version?

Comment: I heard *someone* here on SO say that GAS was going to be updated *very soon* to ES6, but I'm not seeing anything about it in a very quick search about it. For now, write in ES5 (or write in esnext and transpile to ES5 later), though not even everything in ES5 is supported. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768501/google-apps-script-javascript-standard-support

Comment: I think that CertainPerformance's comment is correct. In order to use the function of ``Math.trunc()``, for example, how about modifying to ``function MYTRUNC(input) {return input < 0 ? Math.ceil(input) : Math.floor(input);}`` using the Polyfill? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script Javascript Standard Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768501/google-apps-script-javascript-standard-support)

Answer (score 0):

The best reference I have found is from within the online Script Editor's debugger.

Make a breakpoint anywhere in any function.  Then run that function with the bug button to start debugging.  Next, click on the two buttons at the end of the tool bar: "Show inheritance" and "Show all data".

In the debugger, you should see a `this` with a "+" to expand it.  Expand it and then expand `[[prototype]]` to see all the builtin App Script objects (`GmailApp`, etc), then find the next `[[prototype]]` below those to see the standard JavaScript objects such as `Array`, `Math`, `Date`, etc and you can inspect all of the functions that are available from there.