# check if each value in array matches any value in another array using indexOf in google apps scripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, indexof

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
function ccheck(){
  var tkhContacts = SpreadsheetApp.openById('##').getSheetByName('contacts');
  var emf = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('emf').getContacts(); 
  var fullNames = emf.map( function(contact){ return contact.getFullName() } );
  var tkhContacts = tkhContacts.getRange('B2:B').getValues();

   for(var i=0;i<fullNames.length;i++){
         if(fullNames[i].indexOf(tkhContacts) == -1){
       Logger.log('missing')}
     }
   }
```

Trying to put all Google contacts in group 'emf' into an array. Then taking contact names stored in column B in sheet and putting that in an array. Then take each name in the 'fullNames' array and check if it matches any of the names in 'tkhContacts' from the sheet. If a name in 'fullNames' does not match any name in 'tkhContacts' set value as false.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using the wrong indexOf method.  It looks like you are using the [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) rather than [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

This *should* work for your code, but it is hard to test without any data.

```
const a = ['Sally', 'Walker', 'Claire', 'Lilly'];
const b = ['Kyle', 'Sally', 'Walker', 'Caroline', 'Claire'];

const d_hash = {};
const d_list = [];

a.forEach(a => {
  const i = b.indexOf(a);
  if (i === -1) {
    // the name is missing
    d_hash[a] = {
      status: 'missing',
      index: null
    };
    d_list.push(a);
  } else {
    // the name has been found
    d_hash[a] = {
      status: 'found',
      index: i
    }
  }
});

console.log(d_hash);
console.log(d_list);
```

**The logic:**

- I have two arrays of names, array `a` and array `b`.  I want to find the names that appear in `a` but not in `b`.
- For each value of a, try to find the index of the element in b.  If the index is -1, we know the element could not be found.
- Store the results as a hash and also the list of names that could not be found in an array.
- [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/wiqiloz/edit?js,console)

**Alternatively**

What you are really wanting the do is find the difference of Set `a` and Set `b`.

- [A Set is a data structure that contains many elements and an element can only appear once it each set.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [And a difference is also known as find the complement of a set.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory))

We can convert each array to a set and then perform a difference to get the elements that appear in one but not the other.

```
const a = ['Sally', 'Walker', 'Claire', 'Lilly'];
const b = ['Kyle', 'Sally', 'Walker', 'Caroline', 'Claire'];

const set_a = new Set(a);
const set_b = new Set(b);

// code adapted from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set
Set.prototype.diff = function (b) {
  const d = new Set(a);
  b.forEach(el => d.delete(el));
  return d;
}

console.log(Array.from(set_a.diff(set_b))); // ["Lilly"]
```

**Clarifications:**

- What is forEach?

For each is a method natively provided on the Array.prototype in newer browsers.  [More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

forEach should be applied to an array, and the method expects a function callback that should handle each element.

- What is `(...) => { ... }` ?

This represents [arrow functions which are available in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).  This arrow syntax provides an alternative (and in my opinion, cleaner and clearer) way to define functions.

Something that which was previously represented as:

```
function (el) {
  d.delete(el);
}
```

Can be shortened to

```
(el) => d.delete(el);
```

Comment: What is `el` in ` b.forEach(el => d.delete(el));` ?

Comment: Great question, for you to understand this take a look at these two articles before you read my answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions -- okay now we know that `forEach` expects a function callback as the parameter, and ES6 introduced arrow functions, a shorted (and imo cleaner) function syntax.  So `(el) => d.delete(el));` is equiv to `function (el) => { d.delete(el); }; `

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately Google apps scripts doesn't do well with a lot of ES6.

Comment: You can manually convert it to the older syntax, but from a good code perspective, you should probably be transpiling the JS in general, linting and minifying it. [Check out transpiled ES6 with Google Apps Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820120/using-transpiled-es6-in-google-apps-script-referenceerror-someclass-is-not).